# Change value within a file using PlistBuddy

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, plist

I need to change the value inside a plist, actually would be the value of the vendor and device ID, for example: 0x04128086 and change it to 0x0a168086, wanted an example of doing this using PlistBuddy, Since I intend to use in a shell script.

change this: 
`IOPCIPrimaryMatch 0x0d268086 0x0a268086 0x0a2e8086 0x0d228086  0x04128086`

for this: 
`IOPCIPrimaryMatch 0x0d268086 0x0a268086 0x0a2e8086 0x0d228086 0x0a168086`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a simple perl script.

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's|0x04128086|0x0a168086|g' /System/Library/Extensions/YourFile.kext/Contents/Info.plist
```